# Yahoo Pipes: How to convert an item to a string?

Tags: pipe, yahoo

I need to put one element into another module that receives a text.

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit?_id=b9a50a93a401f07c864df0b039ade3a8